# How to add if statement in anonymous class?

Tags: c#

If I have this :

```
SubMenuList=new object[]
{
    new 
    { 
        transKey = "PERSONAL_INFORMATION",
        stateName="account.personalinformation", 
        displayUrl = "/account/personalinformation" 
    },
    new 
    { 
        tranKey = "NOTIFICATIONS",
        stateName = "account.notificationsettings",
        displayUrl = "/account/notifications"
    }
}
```

Can I somehow add an `if` statement to this and say for example:

```
if (something != null)
{
    new
    {
        transKey = "PERSONAL_INFORMATION", 
        stateName="account.personalinformation", 
        displayUrl = "/account/personalinformation" 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to add `PERSONAL-INFORMATION` to list only if the condition is true? or what is your question?

Comment: yes i want to add personal information if condition is true

Comment: Simple solution, use a real type, rather than an anonymous one, use a list rather than array and do `if (something != null) { list.Add(data); }`

Comment: @DavidArno its not that simple :)

Comment: @AlexSikilinda is that possible?

Comment: @None, why? You are misusing anonymous types. What's so difficult with doing it properly?

Comment: @None is that possible?  No. its not possible. but you can do it in another way that suggested in answer. you cant break the rules.

Comment: @DavidArno problem is that i need to pass that values from class to angular...and i dont know how with real type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose is better to use `List<Object>`:

```
var list = new List<object>
{
    new 
    { 
        transKey = "PERSONAL_INFORMATION",
        stateName="account.personalinformation", 
        displayUrl = "/account/personalinformation" 
    }
};
if (something != null)
{
    list.Add(new
             {
                 tranKey = "NOTIFICATIONS",
                 stateName = "account.notificationsettings",
                 displayUrl = "/account/notifications"
             });
}
```

if you want to get an array, you can invoke `ToArray()` on the link:

```
SubMenuList = list.ToArray();
```

It is better to introduce non anonymous type here, because these objects have the same structure, and without the context it is hard to guess why you do not use named types.

Comment: @AlexSikillnda im using anonymous type becuse i dont know how to pass values from non anonmous type to $scope in angular...do u know ?

Comment: @None, C# knows nothing about angular, so I suspect it is an API which is used by Angular app. I also suspect that it is serialized to JSON, but it is possible to serialize named types to the same JSON as anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list with real type, as suggested by @DavidArno, and add the new item to the list if `something != null`.

You can also use anonymous types:

```
var list = new[]
{
    new 
    { 
        transKey = "PERSONAL_INFORMATION",
        stateName="account.personalinformation", 
        displayUrl = "/account/personalinformation" 
    },
    new 
    { 
        transKey = "NOTIFICATIONS",
        stateName = "account.notificationsettings",
        displayUrl = "/account/notifications"
    }
}.ToList()

if (something != null)
{
    list.Add(new
    {
        transKey = "PERSONAL_INFORMATION", 
        stateName="account.personalinformation", 
        displayUrl = "/account/personalinformation" 
    });
}
```

If you don't need to access the members of the anonymous type (e.g. `list[0].transKey`) or are okay with using reflection, Alex's answer might be better suited for your question.

Comment: i cant use ToList() because im using var list = new object[]

Comment: You can always cast the list to an object array using list.Cast<object>().ToArray()